# Non typical url in urls?

Tags: django, django-urls

if you can get the url in this form:

```
http://host/m,2,o,12,s,9508406-wure-toieut-oiewu-toewiu-toerwupto-iuewoptiuewop-te/
```

in url i have:

```
url(r'^m,(\d+),o,(?P<itemId>\d+),s,(\s+)/$', show_item_by_id),
```

but this is not working. The error is:

```
Using the URLconf defined in portal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
...
^m,(\d+),o,(?P<itemId>\d+),s,(\s+)/$
...
```

How to write this?

Comment: The first problem is that your regex contains ***o*** and your url contains ***s***. If there is still a problem afterwards please provide the error message

Comment: No, i write with error, url: http://host/m,2,o,12,s,9508406-wure-toieut-oiewu-toewiu-toerwupto-iuewoptiuewop-te/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out man, `\s` matches whitespace characters. So you might want to try something along the lines of:

```
url(r'^m,(\d+),o,(?P<itemId>\d+),s,([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$', show_item_by_id),
```

If you want a wider range of characters than the `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]`, you can also try `\S`, which matches all non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Then it won't work, because there has to be at least one character. If you want that url to work, replace `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)` with `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)`